# Need serversocketchannel accept 1000 TCP connection per second

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, nio, serversocket

I am using below code for connecting for my custom java nio server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

String value[] = { "00*********402", "00*********383",.....}
        int i = 0;

            while (i < value.length) {
                RunnableDemo temp = new RunnableDemo(value[i]);
                temp.start();
                i++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); //REDUCING THIS TIME CAUSE PROBLEM
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;

    private Thread t;

    private String threadName;// equals with client number

    RunnableDemo(int phoneNumber) {
        threadName = String.valueOf(phoneNumber);
        System.err.println("Creating " + threadName);

    }

    RunnableDemo(String phoneNumber) {
        threadName = phoneNumber;
        System.err.println("Creating " + threadName);

    }

    public void run() {
        System.err.println("Running " + threadName);
        try {

            //socket = new Socket("94.232.174.97", 4664);
            socket = new Socket("192.168.20.22", 4664);
            PrintWriter testWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream()));
            testWriter.print(threadName);
            testWriter.flush();

            String incoming_message = "";
            BufferedReader bufferedIn = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (true) {
                if (bufferedIn != null) {
                    incoming_message = bufferedIn.readLine();
                    System.out.println("recived message: " +  incoming_message );
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }

    public void read() {

    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        try {
            if (t == null) {
                t = new Thread(this, threadName);
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

it is working fine when I create client threads each 1000 mls but when I reduce the time to 100mls (connecting 10 clients to server per second) after a few second my client threads receive below error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at RunnableDemo.run(Main.java:419)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the server part too:

```
public class EchoServer {

static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

private final static int DEFAULT_PORT = 4664;
private InetAddress hostAddress = null;

private int port;
private String ipAddress = "192.168.20.22";
private Selector selector;

// The buffer into which we'll read data when it's available
private ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);

int timestamp = 1;

HashMap<Integer, String> connectedClients = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> clientIds= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
HashMap<String, String> messageToClients = new HashMap<String, String>();


public EchoServer() {
    this(DEFAULT_PORT);
}

public EchoServer(int port)  {
    try{
        this.port = port;
        hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        selector = initSelector();
        loop();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Exception Accoured:",ex);
    }
}

private Selector initSelector()  {
    try{
        Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(hostAddress, port);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(isa);
        serverChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        return socketSelector;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Exception Accoured:",ex);
        return null;
    }
}

private void loop() {
    while (true) {
        try {

            // Do defined operations for clients
            // ------------------------------
            selector.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys()
                    .iterator();

            int c = 0;
            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = selectedKeys.next();
                selectedKeys.remove();

                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    logger.warn(key.hashCode() + "- is invalid");
                    continue;
                }
                // Check what event is available and deal with it
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    accept(key);
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    read(key);
                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    write(key);
                }
                c++;

            }

            logger.info(c + "  keys has been iterated");

            // Fetch List from server
            // -----------------------------------------
            try {
                ResultSet resultset = DataBase.getInstance()
                        .getQueryResult();


                while (resultset.next()) {
                    String mobileNumber = resultset.getString("MobileNo");

                    String message = resultset.getInt("IsMessage") + ","
                            + resultset.getInt("IsDeliver") + ","
                            + resultset.getInt("IsGroup") + ","
                            + resultset.getInt("IsSeen");
                    messageToClients.put(mobileNumber, message);

                }



            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("Exception Accoured:",ex);
            }

            // Wait for 1 second
            // -----------------------------------------------
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            timestamp++;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}

private void accept(SelectionKey key)  {

    try{
        // Initialize the connection ------------------------------------------
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key
                .channel();
        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socketChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        socketChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.TCP_NODELAY, true);
        logger.info("New client accepted");

        // Fire read for reading phone number --------------------------------
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Exception Accoured:",ex);
    }
}

private void read(SelectionKey key)  {

    try{
        // Initialize Socket -----------------------------------------------------
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();


        // Reading Client Number -------------------------------------------------

        readBuffer.clear();

        int numRead;
        try {
            numRead = socketChannel.read(readBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Forceful shutdown--->" + key.hashCode());
            key.cancel();
            return;
        }

        // read was not successful
        if (numRead == -1) {
            logger.error("Graceful shutdown ---> " + key.hashCode());
            key.cancel();
            return;
        }

        // read was successful and now we can write it to String
        readBuffer.flip();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[readBuffer.limit()];
        readBuffer.get(bytes);

        String number = new String(bytes);

        number = number.replace("\r\n", "");
        number = number.trim();

        // Update Connect Clients Status -----------------------------------------
        Integer clientId=clientIds.get(number);
        if ( clientId == null) {
            connectedClients.put(key.hashCode(), number);
            clientIds.put(number, key.hashCode());
            logger.error(number + "- (" + key.hashCode() + ") has Connected");
        }else{
            connectedClients.remove(clientId);
            connectedClients.put(key.hashCode(), number);
            clientIds.put(number, key.hashCode());
            logger.error(number + "- (" + key.hashCode() + ") REconnected");
        }

        logger.error("All clients number are:" + connectedClients.size());

        // Fire Write Operations -------------------------------------------------
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        //ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception Accoured:",ex);
    }
}

private void write(SelectionKey key)  {
    try {

        //Check channel still alive ----------------------------------------------

        String clientNumber = connectedClients.get(key.hashCode());

        if(clientNumber == null){
            key.cancel();
            logger.info("key with hash=" + key.hashCode() + " canceled");
            return;
        }

        // Get Channel -----------------------------------------------------------
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        // Send Message if client number have new message ------------------------

        if (messageToClients.get(clientNumber) != null) {
            logger.info(clientNumber + "-" + key.hashCode()
                            + "- Sent write message");
            String timeStamp = String.valueOf(timestamp);
            String message = messageToClients.get(clientNumber);
            ByteBuffer dummyResponse = ByteBuffer.wrap((message + "\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            socketChannel.write(dummyResponse);
            messageToClients.remove(clientNumber);
        }

        // Fire new write state --------------------------------------------------
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    } catch (IOException iox) {
        logger.error("Exception Accoured:key=" + key.hashCode(),iox);
        logger.info("$$$key with hash=" + key.hashCode() + " canceled");
        key.cancel();
    } 
}
```

maybe there is a limit on accept connections per second on a port?! I need to at least accept 1000 tcp connection per second. can some body help?

**UPDATE**

I update the amount of pending intents to 1000 by using this line of code:

```
serverChannel.socket().bind(isa,1000);
```

now it receives more clients but still after a few seconds I receive `connection refuse` error.

Comment: There is a limit on how many pending connections can exist at once, determined by the server, and if your server is slow accepting connections that will affect the maximum rate. You need to show the relevant parts of your server code.

Comment: Eh? *I* asked *you* to post your server code.

Comment: I post my server code too.

Comment: when I reduced server wait to 10 mlilisecond it worked. How can I increase the amount of pending connection?

Comment: Increase the backlog parameter in the call of `bind(SocketAddress local, int backlog)`

Comment: I just increased it, it now accept more clients but still receiving same error after 200 clients

Comment: If you are making requests faster than the server can handle, it has to break at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wasting time in your select loop doing database operations, which is rate-limiting your incoming connections. Don't do this. The only blocking operation in the select loop should be the select itself.

And you're wasting yet more time doing a one-second sleep between select calls. There is no reason whatsover to do this. Just get rid of it.

NB When read() returns -1 you must close the channel, not just cancel the key. Otherwise you are leaking channels.